# Assign attribute web control

Tags: asp.net, variables, web-controls

I have dropdownlist with text to display and value as hidden value.
I want keep changing value tooltip as value when user select other selection.
Well, I am already try this code but not work properly:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBranch" runat="server" Width="350px" ToolTip='<% ddlBranch.Value %>'>
```

Display in firefox dropdownlist tooltip as <% ddlBranch.Value %>

Regard

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= DropDownList1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
      {
        DropDownList1.Items[i].Attributes.Add("Title", DropDownList1.Items[i].Text);

      }
```